# Can't run NUnit tests for x86 projects

Tags: testing, .net-core, x86, nunit, 32bit-64bit

I can't run NUnit tests, after I changed the 'Platform target:' to x86.

I'm using a .NET Core 2.2 project in VisualStudio 2019 and I'm running my tests with ReSharper. The NUnit Version is 3.11.0.
The following example works for x64, but does not for x86:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Assert.Pass();
    }
}
```

'Test1 Ignored: VsTest test-case is missing. Rebuild the project and try again.'
So it seems like that the test is no longer identified as a NUnit Test and that the IDE tries to interpret it as a mstest?
Rebuilding does not help.

Comment: Forgive me if it seems like a silly thing to comment, but have you tried right clicking on your project and doing a clean Rebuild? If so, did it change the outcome?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it. Yes, I tried cleaning and rebuilding and also restarting. If I rebuild the whole solution, nothing changes. If I only rebuild the project like you are mentioning, the tests are not displayed in the test session at all, until I rebuild the whole solution. Then they are shown again with the error message from the description.

Comment: I can't run XUnit tests on x64 due to the same error, and it seems, it's a bug in Rider: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-473793